# Is there way to put prompt choice in conversation update and tell what choice will do?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

We are currently working on the proactive chat bot and We want to welcome users with welcome text and prompt choices. I can do prompt choices to work with conversation update but not sure how to do if respone = yes.

I already tried putting in Main dialog but you can't put in the conversation update. using waterfall method.

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    //original
    if (turnContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(turnContext));
    }

    //Welcome user when they join the conversation
    if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded != null)
        {
            foreach (var member in turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Ah yes, {WelcomeText}", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                    var dialogContext = await dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                    await dialogContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt",
                        new PromptOptions
                        {
                            Prompt = dialogContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply(" Your task:  + taskName +  failed because of the following error message: it wasn't able to Auto Login to the runner."),
                            Choices = new[] { new Choice { Value = "Rerun your Task" }, new Choice { Value = "No" } }.ToList()
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be Choices with Rerun your task and NO. if they say no, end dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use conversationUpdate as a means for greeting a user. As detailed in this [blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/12/how-to-properly-send-a-greeting-message-and-common-issues-from-customers/), conversationUpdate is triggered when both the bot and the user join the conversation. However, in a production environment, that doesn't always happen simultaneously. The result is the dialog stack isn't fully constructed and, subsequently, doesn't always have access to the details it needs for sending a greeting (for example, a user's name). The end result is a broken user experience.

I don't know which platform / channel you are using, but the blog referenced suggests using back channel in a web chat environment for monitoring and triggering an event to send a welcome message upon a user joining a conversation. If this is for web chat, keep in mind that the blog is slightly outdated. It explains using BotChat which is the v3 web chat method. The v4 method uses the enhanced [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) which affords greater functionality.

You can experiment with the middleware options to see if there is another option that might work for you. I was unable to find an appropriate one. That being said, the Bot Framework SDKs are open source and always welcome user generated solutions, should you find one.

Comment: Hi Steven, I will be using Teams for this bot. I'm building this in Bot Framework v4. Having struggle with this and how to send proactive notifications to team memeber based on their email

Comment: @H.Birdi, sorry I just saw your message. Are you still having issues with this for Teams?